# Push notification never received from APN

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Ok, after considerable reading and debugging, this is what I know so far:

a) My app *is* registering for push correctly - I can see the APSD logging successful key registration.

b) My message send is getting as far as the APS at least

c) I get nothing back from the Feedback Server

d) I never get "Received message for enabled topic" for my app

Other tests:

i) I can run openssl against both sandbox and push servers with no errors

ii) I can telnet to all three hosts

So I'm thinking that the server is not accepting the message and silently failing. Apple suggests several reasons this might happen, but I don't know how to test these possibilities though.

Any suggestions?

Comment: which server you are using to send push?

Comment: The PHP one from Ray's site, as well as another that is working fine with another app.

Comment: have you tried sending push from your macbook?

Comment: The PHP is on my Mac.

Comment: check your php code and pem file i.e (certificates and privatekey combination), use proper server url like sandbox url for development and other for distribution, If you are getting push token successfully from server while registration process with development profile it means that your certificate and profile is active and working correctly for APNS there should be some thing wrong while receive (check delegates for remote notification) and also pem file and php code.

Comment: I only have one PEM (long story) for deployment. I am using the production message server. I have run the openssl test on the PEM, it seems to work. Is there anything else I can do to test it? Is there any way to tell if they are in error?